# avr debugWIRE On chip debug system

Tags: microcontroller, avr, datasheet

I am new into avr and am working on atmega328p. I am not able to understand the avr debugwire system. What is this and how it works. I am seen the datasheet but am not getting a good clear understanding regarding its use and application. Is it a serial connection for prgramming the IC or what?? Kindly help me in its concept.
[image]

link: [ATmega328p](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Have you checked the manufacturer's promotional materials on the interface?

Comment: No I m going through the datasheet first.

Comment: Well, then do your homework, and come back to enhance/delete your question, please. ;-) "_Is it a serial connection for prgramming the IC or what?_" is already answered right in the marked statement.

Comment: Yes. It is serial interface pro programming and debugging this AVR microcontroller.